# Представление списка в hex формате

Tags: python

Есть список

```py
List = ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

Как привести его к виду `0b1010001`, а затем в `hex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно привести к int и далее куда требуется.

```
l = ['1','0','1','0','0','0','1'] 
val_int = int("".join(l), 2)
val_hex = hex(val_int)
val_bin = bin(val_int)
```